# Force predictions of 2 time series models with different steps to be consistent

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, bayesian, forecasting, modeling

Suppose I have a time series. Let's say it is of the number of sales in a shop. Suppose I am looking to make two models - **model 1** which predicts future values by weekly time steps (total sales per week, i.e. 1-7 days from now, then 8-14 days from now, then 15-21, etc.) and **model 2** which predicts future values by monthly time steps (total sales per month).

Note that I have not decided what models each of these will be yet. But I **cannot** assume that the data/features used to train each model will be the same.

Let's say I make predictions with both models for the period of time ranging from the start of September to the end of October (inclusive). So this is 3 months, in total consisting of exactly 13 weeks. Therefore I will have 13 predictions from model 1, and 3 predictions from model 2.

Let $S_1$ be the sum of the 13 predictions for model 1, and $S_2$ be the sum of the 3 predictions for model 2. How can I ensure that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the same?

Answer (score 1):

One challenge is that 13 weeks and 3 months are not necessarily the same time period: September to November is 91 days and 13 weeks, but October to December is 92 days. But let's not focus on that.

The simplest approach would be to post-process your forecasts, scaling both to achieve the same sum. One possibility for the target common sum would be the average of the two:

$$ S := \frac{S_1+S_2}{2}, $$

but you could use any other value for $S$, like $S:=S_1$ (scaling the monthly predictions to equal the sum of the weekly ones), or $S:=S_2$ (the other way around).

Once you have $S$, simply scale all the weekly predictions by a factor of $\frac{S}{S_1}$, and all the monthly ones by a factor of $\frac{S}{S_2}$. Then the new weekly forecasts and the new monthly forecasts will both sum up to $S$.

If you want to delve deeper, there are some papers on the Multiple Aggregation Prediction Algorithm (MAPA) like Kourentzes et al. (2014) where you take forecasts on different temporal granularities and [optimally combine them along the grouping hierarchy](https://otexts.com/fpp3/reconciliation.html), but this is a bit more advanced and more general.